# Align the content of a TextField, but keep its width x height

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, textfield, center-align

In a card game I use a TextField in the middle to display the playing table number, but also to detect if a playing card has been played - using `myTextField.hitTestObject(myCard)` - which means the TextField's position and dimensions may not change:

[image]

My current AS3 code is:

```
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        format.size = 30;
        format.bold = true;

        myTextField.defaultTextFormat = format;
        myTextField.border = true;
        myTextField.borderColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        myTextField.x = W/2-Card.W/2;
        myTextField.y = Card.H;
        myTextField.width = Card.W;
        myTextField.height = Card.H/4;

        addChild(myTextField);
```

However the TextField's content (the String `"#2029"` in the above screenshot) is not in the center of it.

I can not set `_middle.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER` because this changes the width of the border and breaks `hitTestObject()`.

Is there another way to align the text in the middle please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `align` property of `TextFormat`.

`format.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;`